# matrix - no rows exist please add one

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

Is is possible to change this message so it is more user friendly?

I would like to do it per-field rather than globally.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override these messages in `system/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/language/english/lang.matrix.php`.

In this file you can edit the bits of text between quotes (after the arrow).

Note that these changes will be lost after an update of Matrix.